# Class Is Not Working After Enable Cache in Magento

Tags: php, class, magento, caching

I created separate PHP pages for Magento; and they are all working fine. (about.php, help.php, etc.. I'm calling all necessary blocks, classes etc)

I created a custom class in these pages:

```
class Custom_Work {  }
```

and then, I wrote an if condition in top.phtml(header menu) which checks if there is a class named Custom_Work or not.

```
<?php if (class_exists('Custom_Work')) { echo "YES"; } else { echo "NO"; }  ?
```

When I disable caches in admin panel, everything works fine; in my custom pages it says Yes, but other Magento pages it says no (because Custom_Work class is only at my own pages)

but when I enable caches; it all crashes. It doesn't see my custom class even when I refresh my own php pages; and all pages returns NO..

Do you have any idea, why top.phtml doesn't detect my custom class, which declared in about.php, while all caches are enable?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing closing php tag.

Comment: Thank you Sagar, but no.. i have to say 'forget this class' after if condition in top.phtml i think... but dont know how :/